# PHP PEAR/DataObject equivalent to Rails' easy ActiveRecord finding functionality

Tags: php, pear, data-objects

In Rails, say a blogging application, given a particular post object you could get the name of the author of the post doing something like:

```
post = Post.find(1)    
author_name = post.author.name
```

Is there a PHP equivalent using DataObject, something like (just making up imaginary syntax here):

```
$postsTable = DB_DataObject::factory('posts');
$authorName = (($postsTable->id = 1)->find(true))->author->name;

              |  finds and autofetches post #1  |->author->name
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want an ORM with an API like that I would recommend [PHP ActiveRecord](http://www.phpactiverecord.org/):

```
$posts = Post::find('all', array('limit' => 10, 'include' => array('author')));
foreach ($posts as $post) {
   echo $post->author->first_name;
}
```

http://www.phpactiverecord.org/projects/main/wiki/Finders

---

You may also be interested in [Propel ORM](http://www.propelorm.org/):

```
$book = BookQuery::create()
  ->useAuthorQuery()
    ->filterByFirstName('Leo')
  ->endUse()
  ->with('Author')
  ->findOne();
$author = $book->getAuthor();
```

http://www.propelorm.org/wiki/Documentation/1.6/Relationships

Answer (score 0):

DB_DataObject does not have a fluent interface so you cannot chain.
However you can do this :

```
$postsTable = DB_DataObject::factory('posts');
if($postsTable->get($id)) {
  $authorname = $postsTable->getLink('author_id')->name;
}
```